# Add TextField in each page of existing pdf using iText

Tags: itext, pdfstamper

I'm trying to add the TextField using iText5 in each page of the existing pdf but I'm able to create only in page 1 but not in all the pages. below is the code snippet.

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("C:/somename.pdf");
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,
                new FileOutputStream("C:/somename_output.pdf"));
pdfStamper.setEncryption(false, null, null, ~PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY);

int pages = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int page = 1; page <= pages; page++) {
            TextField field = new TextField(pdfStamper.getWriter(), new Rectangle(400, 1, 612, 10), "HiddenText");
            field.setBorderColor(BaseColor.CYAN);
            field.setBorderStyle(PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_DASHED);
            field.setBorderWidth(BaseField.BORDER_WIDTH_MEDIUM);
            field.setText("Adding some text here in each page");
            field.setOptions(TextField.READ_ONLY);
            pdfStamper.addAnnotation(field.getTextField(), page);
        
        pdfStamper.close();
        pdfReader.close();

    }
```

The expected output is working only for page 1 not for all. Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the question title and body you mention iText 5 but you have tagged the question with [tag:itext7] - does that imply you would also consider iText 7 based solutions worthwhile?

Comment: @mkl I can upgrade to iText7 if t has some better approach.

Comment: I foremost wondered about this [tag:itext7] tag on an otherwise iText 5 specific question.

Comment: I did not find the itext5 tag in auto suggestions.

Comment: If you hover oder the itext tag, you'll read that it's *for code using iText versions up to 5.5.x*.

Comment: Thank you @mkl, I updated now

Comment: Have you tried giving them different names? I.e. instead of `"HiddenText"` have you tried `"HiddenText" + page`?

Comment: It worked, thanks @mkl